# Make picklist field required based on another picklist field

Tags: validation

IF A(picklist fild=X and B(picklist field=)

Then Return_Type(picklist) and POD_request_status__c(picklist)
can not left as blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation rule like below

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Return_Type__c,'YOUR_LIST_VALUE'),ISPICKVAL(POD_request_status__c,''))
```

If the **`Return_Type__c`** value matched with the value you have given and if the **`POD_request_status__c`** value is null, then the Error will generated accordingly...

Hope this might helps....